# Bound mismatch using DoubleSupplier

Tags: java, graph

I created a class that implements the Dijkstra algorithm on graph.

```
public class Dijkstra<V, E extends DoubleSupplier> {
    ...
}
```

When I try to test this class with JUnit, the compiler generates this error:
**Bound mismatch: The type Integer is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type Dijkstra**

The test class is:

```
public class DijkstraTest {

    Dijkstra<String, Integer> dijkstra = new Dijkstra<String, Integer>();
    ...
}
```

Why? I searched on the web and couldn't find much about it.
Using Java 8.

Thanks

Comment: A `DoubleSupplier` is a generator for double values. It's totally unrelated to the `Integer` class.

Comment: @AlexisC. Thanks, so what should I put in place to Integer? :-/

Comment: Well why do you want a `DoubleSupplier` in first place? Why can't you have `class Dijkstra<V, Number>`?

Comment: @AlexisC. The professor has requested that there was DoubleSupplier..

Comment: Then you can create your own class implementing the `DoubleSupplier` interface.

Comment: @AlexisC. Ok, but why do I need a generator double?It is why I do not understand ..

Comment: Well ask your teacher or the TAs maybe? My guess is that it's for generating values according to the given supplier for the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` does not implement `DoubleSupplier` which is the reason why you can't use `Integer` as second type parameter of `Dijkstra`. Maybe you actually want to add a [`ToDoubleFunction<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToDoubleFunction.html), which allows you to map edges to `double` instead:

```
public class Dijkstra<V, E> {

    private final ToDoubleFunction<E> edgeToWeightFunction;

    public Dijkstra(ToDoubleFunction<E> edgeToWeightFunction) {
        this.edgeToWeightFunction = edgeToWeightFunction;
    }

    private double getEdgeWeight(E edge) {
         return edgeToWeightFunction.applyAsDouble(edge);
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public class DijkstraTest {

    Dijkstra<String, Integer> dijkstra = new Dijkstra<String, Integer>(Integer::doubleValue);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The ToDoubleFunction<E> class what to do?

Comment: @user3808470: The `ToDoubleFunction<E>` is a functional interface that is used to convert a `E` to `double`. There is a link to the javadoc in my answer. It's used e.g. to convert a stream to a `DoubleStream` (see [`java.util.stream.Stream.mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-)). You could also use it to get edge weights from a map or something similar.

Comment: Ok so I could create a function that took as input an E, give me back a double random, I'm right? And the class ToDoubleFunction <E> extends DoubleSupplier?

Comment: @user3808470: No, it doesn't implement `DoubleSupplier`. Instead it's used to convert edges to their weights. Also if even if you use random weights, those weights should be the same if you pass the same object more than once. It basically means you don't require each object to implement `DoubleSupplier`; instead you allow the programmer using your `Dijkstra` class to pass a object that allows him to specify a way to get the edge weights (`double`) for edges.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the fact that you want use "Integer" for something that should "extend DoubleSupplier".

But well, Integer is for sure not implementing that interface; therefore this class can't be used here.

You can write a little wrapper that takes an Integer and implements the "DoubleSupplier" interface accordingly.